# Unable to access Custom Actuator Endpoint in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to create a custom api endpoint for actuator where the endpoint is defined as a separate class and uses @Endpoint annotation

The endpoint is visible when http://~/actuator in the list but somehow when I try to '''GET''' on this  `http://~/actuator/urlshotnerendpoint` , I get `HTTP 500` error

Have posted the code below for reference

CustomEndPoint.java

```
package com.soul1.url_shotener_service.endpoint;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.ReadOperation;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;


@Component
@Endpoint(id = "urlshotnerendpoint", enableByDefault = true)
public class CustomEndPoint {
    
    @ReadOperation
    public CustomEndPointResponse features() {
        return new CustomEndPointResponse(12,"name1","status1");
    }
    

}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

class CustomEndPointResponse{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String status;
    
    public CustomEndPointResponse(int id, String name,String status) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.status=status;
        
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The error coming up in the logs in Debug mode is as below

```
2022-10-23 20:30:02.039 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/actuator", parameters={}
2022-10-23 20:30:02.055 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped to Actuator root web endpoint
2022-10-23 20:30:02.155 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json', given [*/*] and supported [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json]
2022-10-23 20:30:02.225 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [{_links={self=[Link@26effc60 href = 'http://localhost:8080/actuator'], urlshotnerendpoint=[Link@4c78 (truncated)...]
2022-10-23 20:30:03.191 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-10-23 20:30:23.318 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/actuator/urlshotnerendpoint", parameters={}
2022-10-23 20:30:23.319 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped to Actuator web endpoint 'urlshotnerendpoint'
2022-10-23 20:30:23.698 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json', given [*/*] and supported [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json]
2022-10-23 20:30:23.704  WARN 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.soul1.url_shotener_service.endpoint.CustomEndPointResponse] with preset Content-Type 'null']
2022-10-23 20:30:23.704 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
2022-10-23 20:30:23.710 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-10-23 20:30:23.792 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2022-10-23 20:30:23.829 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-10-23 20:30:23.996 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/xml;charset=UTF-8, text/xml;charset=UTF-8, application/*+xml;charset=UTF-8, application/xml;charset=UTF-8, text/xml;charset=UTF-8, application/*+xml;charset=UTF-8]
2022-10-23 20:30:24.049 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Oct 23 20:30:23 IST 2022, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, path=/actuator/url (truncated)...]
2022-10-23 20:30:24.060 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-10-23 20:30:24.063 DEBUG 15932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

Thanks in Advance for you help

also

I have a separate  customized health indicator at http://~/actuator/health which is showing up fine without any issues

```
package com.soul.custom_url_shotener_service.health;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class InternalHealthMetrics implements HealthIndicator{
    
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return checkInternet()==true?Health.up().withDetail("success code","Active Internet Connection").build():Health.down().withDetail("error code","InActive Internet Connection").build();     
    }
    
    private boolean checkInternet() {
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            flag=true;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            flag=false;
        }
        
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used this, but the error says expected content-type is null. @ReadOperation looks like it takes a produces parameter. Did you try to set that application/json?

Comment: I ran with setting ```@ReadOperation(produces = "application/json")``` still not running

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your application.properties file

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=urlshotnerendpoint